Passing array to WHERE IN on multiple columns in a function
I have a table as following:
create table test
(
  id varchar(20),
  text varchar(20)
);
    
insert into test values(1, 'a')
insert into test values(2, 'b')
insert into test values(3, 'c')

To check multi-column in where condition, I can do this:
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE (id, text) = ANY (VALUES('1', 'a')
                            , ('2', 'b')
                            , ('3', 'c'));

I have a function that takes 2 arrays as input:
create or replace function test_function
(
    p_ids     in varchar[],
    p_texts   in varchar[]
)
returns table (p_id   varchar,
               p_text varchar) as $$
begin
    return query 
    SELECT id, text 
    FROM test 
    WHERE (id, text) = ANY (VALUES('1', 'a')
                                , ('2', 'b')
                                , ('3', 'c'));
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

My question is, what is the most efficient (performance-wise) way to to replace ANY (VALUES('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c')) with the actual array input (p_ids and p_texts)?

"Most efficient" in terms of syntax
Some of the choices are:

INNER JOIN with variadic unnest() instead of filtering in WHERE
Single-argument unnest() in a row() constructor, inside an array() constructor
Variadic unnest() in that or an IN subquery

The first one is not only the shortest, but also the quickest, as demonstrated lower in this post.
demo at db<>fiddle
create or replace function test_function
(   p_ids     in varchar[],
    p_texts   in varchar[]
)
returns table (p_id   varchar,
               p_text varchar) as $f$
begin
    return query 
    SELECT id, text 
    FROM test 
    JOIN unnest(p_ids,p_texts)AS u(id,text) USING(id,text);
    --NATURAL JOIN unnest(p_ids,p_texts)AS u(id,text); --discouraged syntax
    --WHERE (id, text) = ANY(ARRAY(select (unnest(p_ids),unnest(p_texts))));
    --WHERE (id, text) = ANY(ARRAY(select u from unnest(p_ids,p_texts)u));
    --WHERE (id, text) IN (select*from unnest(p_ids,p_texts));
end;
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select*from test_function('{1,2,3,8,9}','{a,b,c,x}');




p_id
p_text




1
a


2
b


3
c



Watch out for null-padding in case they are of different length
select row( unnest(array['a','b','c','d'])
           ,unnest(array[1,2])
          ); 




row




(a,1)


(b,2)


(c,)


(d,)




"Most efficient" in terms of performance
The join with variadic unnest() seems to perform best here (execution times in seconds, lower is better):
demo2 at db<>fiddle



variant
avg
a
min
mi
max
mx
sum
sm
stddev
st
mode
md




join_variadic_unnest
0.000297
1
0.000240
2
0.000469
1
0.006236
1
0.000080
1
0.000242
2


in_variadic_unnest
0.001278
2
0.000162
1
0.022200
2
0.026829
2
0.004795
2
0.000170
1


array_row_2unnest
0.469599
3
0.459486
4
0.492036
4
0.861575
3
0.009940
3
0.459486
4


array_variadic_unnest
0.469757
4
0.442742
3
0.490769
3
0.864888
4
0.013638
4
0.442742
3



Above are timings of each method searching a few times for 11 rows that match two 20-element arrays in a 50k sample.
Here's the two winners searching 100 times for 262 rows based on two 50-element arrays in a 500k sample:



variant
avg
a
min
mi
max
mx
sum
sm
stddev
st
mode
md




join_variadic_unnest
0.000497
1
0.000314
1
0.003766
1
0.050234
1
0.000565
1
0.000316
1


in_variadic_unnest
0.000558
2
0.000343
2
0.006439
2
0.056383
2
0.000793
2
0.000345
2




Note that you can use your target table as if it was a type:
demo3 at db<>fiddle
create or replace function test_function
(   tests   in test[] 
)returns setof test as 
$f$ SELECT id
         , text 
    FROM test 
    NATURAL JOIN unnest(tests);
$f$ language SQL;

Then
select*from test_function(array[ (1,'a')::test
                                ,(2,'b')::test
                                ,(3,'c')::test])

Or
select*from test_function('{"(1,a)","(2,b)","(3,c)"}'::test[])


Thank you very much, this is better than I expected! I was asking from a performance point of view, but the additional syntax perspective you made is fantastic as well.
